# How do I exclude some I/O variables I don't need from being stored in memory?

Tags: openmdao

My simple workflow can now take up to 9 GB of RAM every time I run the model (without the driver).

This is because I'm running many cases with one of the components in a vectorized way. This means I've made one component that takes in an N-shaped input, operates on it and outputs an N-shaped vector too.

Is there a way to tell OpenMDAO not to store in its dictionaries some the outputs of certain intermediate components that don't provide the design variables nor the constraints values?

Comment: its not clear what you mean by "store", "intermediate", and "vectorized" in this context. Do you have one component with an array of length n output? Or did you make n components each with a scalar output? What are the sizes of variables you're using in your components? 

could you post a representative example to clarify your use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMDAO's memory usage doesn't come from storing I/O values. The problem was that I had declared in an N-input to N-output Component that the partial derivatives were of the form `(from=['*'], wrt=['*']).` This defines the Jacobian as completely dense, and in my case it was much sparser than this because the component was doing a vectorized computation. So its Jacobian was diagonal.

As of OpenMDAO 2.0.2, large dense jacobians use a lot of memory, and specifying the sparsity is highly recommended. By defining the partials with the `rows` and `cols` arguments, memory usage went from 13 GB down to 200 MB. See: http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/2.0.2/feature_reference/core_features/working_with_derivatives/sparse_partials.html